# Enable feature folders structure for area and get all controllers namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have enabled feature folders structure in my project only for the areas part.

To explain why i did that, it's because i have simply too many controllers in my areas (over 100 controllers) and it's not even the half of the program.

Any way, using the below code, i have enabled feature folders for area:

```
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine()
        {
            AreaViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                "~/Areas/{2}/Features/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Areas/{2}/Features/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            },
            AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                "~/Areas/{2}/Features/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Areas/{2}/Features/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            },
            AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
            {
                "~/Areas/{2}/Features/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                "~/Areas/{2}/Features/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            },
            FileExtensions = new[]
            {
                "cshtml",
            },
        });
```

It's work fine, but there is the namespace problem for controllers with the same name, like Home Controller.

For this problem i'm using refactoring to get all namespace for routing configuration.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        var namespaces = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof (AdminBaseController).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.Name.StartsWith("T4MVC_"))
            .Select(x => x.Namespace).ToArray();

        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: namespaces
        );
    }
```

My question is: Is this a good way to handle too many controllers? and also is there a better way to register route with namespaces?

```
-Areas
 --Admin
   ---Features
      ----Home
          *HomeController
          *Index.cshtml
          *IndexViewModel.cs
-Controllers
 *HomeController
-Models
 --Home
   *IndexViewModel
-Views
 --Home
   *Index.cshtml
```

Comment: you have to explicitly specify the namespace restriction

Comment: Here you you specify all the namespaces as a restriction to your area.Instead You can restrict to the namespace specific to the area